# Checking if UNIXTIMESTAMP is within the last 60 seconds for all users to count users online

Tags: php, mysql, unix-timestamp

So, I'm trying to properly check UNIX timestamp to count users online. The way I am trying to do so is if the user is active on a page it updates their user data with the current UNIX Timestamp. The I am trying to check all users as shown below but instead even if they arent active it shows everyone is online. This seems to work on my local server but not my web server. What am I doing wrong here?

```
            $SQLR = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `users`");
            $rowUsers = mysqli_fetch_assoc($SQLR);

            $diffOnline = time() - $rowUsers["activity"];
            $countOnline = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE {$diffOnline} < 60");
            $onlineCount = mysqli_fetch_column($countOnline);

            echo $onlineCount;
```

Expecting it to count the amount of users active within the last min.

Comment: your query for $rowUsers says: SELECT * FROM `users`. you are basically selecting ALL users,not just the active ones. which column do you use in the database to check if a user is active?

Comment: @Mashtan Would be the 11th so code wise 10th
https://imgur.com/76DPt6O

Comment: What's the column type of `activity`? Is it really a numeric column type?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're just missing the field name (activity) in your second select.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE `activity` > unix_timestamp()-60
```